# Add new object in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm working with javascript and JSON. I have a JSON object like this one:

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"}
```

In my case, I have a function like this one:

```
function addNewValues(jsonArray, firstName, lastName, id)
```

In case the "firstName" is not a match, I should create a new value in the array.

From

```
addNewValues({"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"}, "Jane", 
"Doe", "2");
```

it should return:

```
[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"},
{"firstName":"Jane", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"2"}
]
```

How can I add this new position? 
I tried 
    `myObj.push({"firstName":firstName, "lastName":lastName });`
without any success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: return [jsonArray,{firstName,lastName,id}];

Comment: `JSON.parse` your `JSON`, `push` the item and then `JSON.stringify` to have a `JSON`. Or work with `array of objects` and `JSON.stringify` when you have the need of `JSON`.

Comment: By the way, your array isnt one...

Comment: There's a much of confusion going on between JSON, arrays and objects here. An object doesn't have the `push()` method, an array has. You should be very careful with what you are doing - having both an array or an object being returned from your function will most probably lead to a mess.

Comment: What should happen if the first name matches?

Comment: @baao if the first name matches, the rest of the records are updated. That already is implemented and working.

Comment: ok, answered your question below

Comment: @zoealonso: this is not a forum, don't change the title with [SOVLED], but rather accept an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** method to test if the given array doesn't contain an object with this `firstName`, then push a new object with these properties.

This is how should be your code:

```
function addNewValues(jsonArray, firstName, lastName, id){
     if(!jsonArray.some(function(obj){
         return obj.firstName === firstName;
      })){
          jsonArray.push({"firstName": firstName, "lastName" : lastName, "id": id});
      };
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var jsonArray = [{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"}];

function addNewValues(jsonArray, firstName, lastName, id){
     if(!jsonArray.some(function(obj){
         return obj.firstName === firstName;
      })){
          jsonArray.push({"firstName": firstName, "lastName" : lastName, "id": id});
      };
}

addNewValues(jsonArray, "Jane", 
"Doe", "2");

console.log(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your json is a string, you have to parse it with `JSON.parse` and then put it into array if it not.

```js
var array = [];

// with push
function addNewValues(firstName, lastname, id) {
  // check if firstName already exists
  if(array.filter(function(x) { return x.firstName===firstName; }).length===0) {
    array.push({
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastname,
        'id': id
    });
  }
}

// with concat
// I would suggest you to use this method
function addNewValues1(arr, firstName, lastname, id) {
  if(arr.filter(function(x) { return x.firstName===firstName; }).length===0) {
    return arr.concat([{
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastname,
        'id': id
    }]);
  }
  return arr;
}

addNewValues("Jahn", "Doe", "1");
addNewValues("Jane", "Doe", "2");
console.log(array);

// with concat
array = addNewValues1(array, "Foo", "Bar", "3");
console.log(addNewValues1(array, "Foo1", "Bar1", "4"));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok with your code except the line

```
    addNewValues({"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"}, "Jane", "Doe", "2");
```

You are supposed to pass array of JSON (assuming that you have written the function already), but right now you are passing JSON object only .

Try this instead

```
    addNewValues([{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"}], "Jane", "Doe", "2");
```

once you do this , the below mentioned line will execute without any error.

```
    myObj.push({"firstName":firstName, "lastName":lastName });
```

You can also check this working demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obm5kLrt/)

Answer (score 1):

To get that you can use below function. It will update the records if the firstname exists, or it will create a new entry in case it doesn't. Below function will find the first entry with given firstname.

```js
let obj = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "id": "1"
};

function addNewValues(arr, firstName, lastName, id) {
    arr = Array.isArray(arr) ? arr : [arr];
    let obj = arr.find(v => v.firstName === firstName);
    if (! obj) {
        return arr.concat({firstName, lastName, id});
    }
    obj.lastName = lastName;
    obj.id = id;
    return arr;
}

console.log(addNewValues(obj, "Jane", "Foo", 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your call `addNewValues`, you should pass an array as the first parameter (you are passing an object instead):

```
var values = [{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"}];
addNewValues(values , "Jane", "Doe", "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code. Hope this will help to understand your problem. After adding new array, updated value showing in console.

You can read more about [Javascript Array Methods: Unshift(), Shift(), Push(), And Pop()](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1796-javascript-array-methods-unshift-shift-push-and-pop.htm)

```js
var jsonArray=[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"}];

function addNewValues(firstName, lastName, id){
// here you can check if exists or not
jsonArray.push({"firstName":firstName, "lastName":lastName,"id":id });
console.log(jsonArray);
return jsonArray;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick='addNewValues("Jane", 
"Doe", "2"); '>Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/52q9v57j/

```js
var jsonArray = [{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "id":"1"}];

addNewValues = function(jsonArray, firstName, lastName, id){
 return jsonArray.push(
   {"firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "id": id}
  );
}

addNewValues(jsonArray, "Jane", "Doe", "2"); 
console.log(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
newArray = [];
newArray.push(jsonArray);
function addNewValues(newArray, firstname, lastname, id){
    jsonArray.push({
        'firstName': firstname,
        'lastName': lastname,
        'id': id
    });
    return newArray;
}
newArray = addNewValues(newArray, 'Jane', 'Doe', '2');
// newArray now is array of 2 jsonObject
```

Hope this help.